# Distinguish emails I've replied to from those I haven't?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

Since updating to Mac OS 12.4 (from 10.14.6), I notice that the little grey arrow next to email threads in the Mail app now appears next to *any* thread on which I've written a reply, even if the latest message in the thread is incoming from someone else and I haven't replied since it came in.

Of course I consider this is a regression in user experience; I like to know whether I've answered the thread since the last email came in, which is what the little grey arrow used to indicate.

I hope there is an obscure or hidden setting or option somewhere that controls this feature.

Does anyone know of a workaround to restore the previous behavior, or any approximation thereof?

Comment: I'm not sure that's new behaviour, no matter how long an email thread, the 'reply' arrow remains after the first reply. I'm still on Mojave.

Comment: You can create a Smart Mailbox that collects messages that satisfy a set of conditions you specify, which can include the condition that the message was (or was not) replied to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "hidden setting" for this, and that *is* default behavior in Monterey. However, you can set up a Rule to make them appear differently. Rules can be found under Mail -> Preferences (Command-comma) -> Rules. Then add Rules based on if you are the sender of a message and make it a different color if it is. This will make it a whole lot easier to differentiate.